# No puedo elegir elementos en el cuadro de herramientas

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Tengo instalado `Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 2` no se desde que momento dejó de funcionar, lo único que hice fue instalar el `update 2` hace un mes más o menos.

Tengo un control personalizado el cual quiero agregar al `ToolBox` pero cuando le doy en elegir elementos en la pestaña que cree no sucede nada no me muestra la ventana para elegir mi `dll`.

[image: ToolBox]

Comment: Has intentado "Restablecer cuadro de herramientas" para configurarlo desde cero?

Comment: Hola, si ya lo hice y no me ha dado resultados

Comment: validaste que no este ejecutando la aplicacion ? porque si esta en degug no te dejara agregar componentes

Comment: Si, lo que estoy haciendo es volver a instalar el Visual Studio, :(

Comment: Desinstale y volvi instalar VS y no puedo agregar elementos de una dll al ToolBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta arrastrando desde el explorador de archivos el *DLL* que contiene tus controles y suéltalo en la pestaña ***TecSoftware*** que creaste en la barra de herramientas.

Answer (score 0):

La solución está en arrastrar el elemento dll a el cuadro de herramientas.
También tenia este inconveniente porque tengo controles de GUNA y lo e solucionado.